# Plotting multiple lines, want a mark every with a text label on each line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently working on a graph where I have 4 lines going through it. I want to have a bunch of marks on it so that people can get a specific value at that point and time on the graph.

Attached is my example. I have a bunch of lines with various values. I would like to set it up to where every 30 days, it places with a mark on the line with the value of that point. That way people can more easily tell the value.

[image: My Plot]

Example of my dataset

```
             25     50      90      100
2019-04-04  55.0   76.0  1027.0  1200.0
2019-04-05  56.0   77.0  1028.0  1201.0
2019-04-06  57.0   78.0  1029.0  1202.0
2019-04-07  58.0   79.0  1030.0  1203.0
2019-04-08  59.0   80.0  1031.0  1204.0
2019-04-09  60.0   81.0  1032.0  1205.0
2019-04-10  61.0   82.0  1033.0  1206.0
2019-04-11  62.0   83.0  1034.0  1207.0
2019-04-12  53.0   84.0  1035.0  1208.0
2019-04-13  54.0   85.0  1036.0  1209.0
2019-04-14  55.0   86.0  1037.0  1210.0
2019-04-15  56.0   87.0  1038.0  1211.0
2019-04-16  57.0   88.0  1039.0  1212.0
2019-04-17  58.0   89.0  1040.0  1213.0
2019-04-18  59.0   90.0  1041.0  1214.0
2019-04-19  60.0   91.0  1042.0  1215.0
2019-04-20  61.0   92.0  1043.0  1216.0
2019-04-21  62.0   93.0  1044.0  1217.0
2019-04-22  63.0   94.0  1045.0  1218.0
2019-04-23  64.0   95.0  1046.0  1219.0
2019-04-24  65.0   96.0  1047.0  1220.0
2019-04-25  66.0   97.0  1048.0  1221.0
2019-04-26  67.0   98.0  1049.0  1222.0
2019-04-27  68.0   99.0  1050.0  1223.0
2019-04-28  69.0  100.0  1051.0  1224.0
2019-04-29  70.0  101.0  1052.0  1225.0
2019-04-30  71.0  102.0  1053.0  1226.0
2019-05-01  72.0  103.0  1054.0  1227.0
2019-05-02  73.0  104.0  1055.0  1228.0
2019-05-03  74.0  105.0  1056.0  1229.0
```

And the code I am using to plot

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [18, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=panda_data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = df.plot(kind='line')
ax.grid(axis='y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With daily data, use `resample.asfreq()` to get the points every X days (I'll use 15 here for illustration given the date ranges). Then plot them and annotate. Ensuring the labels don't overlap is a much harder task.

For a few points, don't worry too much about the performance of `stack` + `iteritems`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)  # If not a DatetimeIndex
pts = df.resample('15D').asfreq()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

df.plot(kind='line', ax=ax)
pts.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, lw=0, color='black', legend=False)

pad = 10
for idx, val in pts.stack().iteritems():
    ax.annotate(val, (idx[0], val+pad))

ax.grid(axis='y')
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to replicate your pts = part, I get the following error.
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: @Mallachar do `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`